# laravel blade datetime dynamic timezone on view

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, timezone, laravel-blade

I have a view on blade view with DateTime as a column of datatable. the DateTime timezone is UTC. I wanted to change it to the local timezone with the client browser.

so if the data is 00:00 a.m., then for someone accessing from UTC+5, the DateTime will be 05:00.

the column is currently like this, it generates me *2022-01-02 00:00am*:

```
      <td>
        {{ $data->createdDate->format('d M Y H:ia') }}
      </td>
```

and then I try to manipulate the DateTime using the timezone below and it works. but I hard-coded the timezone on it. so I got *2022-01-01 19:00pm* which is correct (UTC-5).

```
 {{ $data->createdDate->setTimezone('America/New_York')->format('d M Y H:ia') }}
```

is there a way to dynamically set the timezone ('America/New_York') on the view page?

because the users could be accessed from different regions.

I know on javascript I can generate the timezone using

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

but how can I pass the timezone to that?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a timestamp to the blade view and then create local time using javascript, something like this:

PHP

```
$dt = new DateTime('2020-12-24 4:45',new dateTimeZone('UTC'));  //example
echo '<div id="datejs" data-ts="'.($dt->getTimeStamp() * 1000;).'">?</div>';
```

Javascript

```
var el = document.getElementById("datejs");
var ts = parseInt(el.getAttribute("data-ts"));
el.innerHTML = new Date(ts).toLocaleString();
```

I tested it without Laravel and Blade. Output for my time zone: 24.12.2020, 05:45:00

If a specific formatting of PHP pages is desired, a format string can also be passed via a data element. A framework such as [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) is then helpful for the formatting itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can add timezone field to users table, then update it once the user login using for example momentjs library on login form.
Finally you can easily display the time according to user timezone, something like this :

```
{{ $data->createdDate->setTimezone(auth()->user()->timezone)->format('d M Y H:ia') }}
```